# How to tell Rails to not clean some assets in the public folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

The issue here is that I have Bootstrap on production looking for the fonts at:

```
assets/spree/fonts/glyphicons-the-file-name.something
```

When in development mode, it looks for these assets in:

```
fonts/glyphicons-the-file-name.something
```

So what I did was I added the `fonts` folder into public and it all worked. I did the same for production. You can guess that I'm now dealing with a `rails assets:clean` issue that must be running and removing the files, hence not allowing them to appear.

Is there a way to tell Rails to not clean the files in `assets/spree/fonts`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you installed the bootstrap files manually?

If you instead use a gem such as the following, then you won't have to worry about these issues:

```
gem "bootstrap-sass"
```

Alternatively, you should be installing everything into your `vendor` directory. As you've found you'll then have issues with any linked assets within these files. The correct fix for this would be to edit the bootstrap source to use the correct `asset_path` helpers.

Obviously that's quite a bit of maintenance overhead when you get round to doing the next bootstrap update.

I'd take a look at the `bootstrap-sass` gem, even if you decide not to use it.

Comment: I haven't installed bootstrap manually, its coming from a gem.

Comment: Which gem are you using? A gem definitely shouldn't require you to copy anything into the `public` directory.